# Why does this merge sort give incorrect results?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

My assignment is to merge two arrays using int arrays that the user fills and we have to assume that there will be a maximum of 10000 inputs from the user, and the user inputs a negative number to stop. Then sort the array from least to greatest and print it out. Initially i thought that this would be quite easy but when i finished, i began getting outputs such as:

```
Enter the values for the first array, up to 10000 values, enter a negative number to quit: 1  
3  
5  
-1  
Enter the values for the second array, up to 10000 values, enter a negative number to quit  
2   
4  
6  
-1  
First Array:  
1   
3   
5  
Second Array:   
2  
4   
6   
Merged Array:  
6 1 2 3 4 5
```

as you can see, the six is out of place and i have no idea how to fix it. Here is the source code, i have included copious comments because I really want you guys to help me out to the best of your abilities. IF it's possible to use the same exact technique without implement new techniques and methods into the code please do so. I know there are methods in java that can do all of this in one line but it's for an assignment at a more basic level.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Merge

{


    public static void main(String [] args)    
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int [] first = new int[10000];          //first array, assume 10k inputs max
    int [] second = new int[10000];         //first array, assume 10k inputs max

    boolean legal = true; //WILL IMPLIMENT LATER


    int end = 0; // set how many elements to put in my "both" array
    int end2 = 0;// set how many elements to put in my "both" array


    System.out.print("Enter the values for the first array, up to 10000 values, enter a negative number to quit");
    //get values
    for(int i = 0; i<first.length; i++)
    {
          first[i] = scan.nextInt(); //fill first with user input

          if(first[i] <0) //if negative number, stop loop
          {
            end = i; //get position of end of user input
            break;
          }
    }

    System.out.println("Enter the values for the second array, up to 10000 values, enter a negative number to quit");

    for(int i = 0; i<second.length; i++) //exact same as the first get values loop
    {
      second[i] = scan.nextInt();

      if(second[i] <0)
      {
        end2 = i;
        break;
      }
    }

    System.out.print("First Array:\n");

    for(int i = 0; i<first.length; i++) //print first array
    {
      if(i == end) //this prevents from printing thousands of zeros, only prints values that user inputed
        break;
      System.out.println(first[i] + " ");
    }


    System.out.print("Second Array:\n"); 

    for(int i = 0; i<second.length; i++) //same as printing first array 
    {
          if(i == end2)
            break;
          System.out.println(second[i] + " ");
    }

    int [] both = new int[(end)+(end2)]; //instanciate an int array to hold only inputted values from first[] and second[]
    int [] bothF = new int[(end)+(end2)]; //this is for my simple sorter algotithm loop

    for(int i = 0; i<both.length; i++) //fill both with the first array that was filled
    {
      both[i] = first[i];
    }

    int temp = end; // see below
    for(int i = 0;i<both.length; i++) //fill array with the second array that was filled(starting from the end of the first array so that the first set is not overwritten
    {
      if(temp<both.length){ //this prevents an out of bounds
      both[temp] = second[i];

        temp++;}
    }

    //simple sorting algorithm
    for(int d = both.length -1;d>=0;d--)
    {    
          for(int i = 0; i<both.length; i++)
           {
                if(both[d]<both[i])
                {
                      bothF[d] = both[d];
                      both[d] = both[i];
                      both[i] = bothF[d];          
                }      
          }
    }

    System.out.println("Merged Array:"); //print the results
    for(int i = 0; i<both.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(both[i] + " ");

    }

    //System.out.println("ERROR: Array not in correct order");    
}
```

Comment: "Fix this" questions are not very popular in SO. Try pinpointing the problem more precisely and I'm sure many folks will be glad to help you.

Comment: +1 You've posted code, example output, and have told us the exact problem with that output.  Congratulations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can do it like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
    both[i] = first[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i < end2; i++) {
    both[i + end] = second[i];
}

// simple sorting algorithm
for (int d = both.length - 1; d >= 0; d--) {
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        if (both[i] > both[d]) {
            int t = both[d];
            both[d] = both[i];
            both[i] = t;
        }
    }
}
```

Output(s) -

```
Enter the values for the first array, up to 10000 values, enter a negative number to quit3
5
-1
Enter the values for the second array, up to 10000 values, enter a negative number to quit
2
4
6
-1
First Array:
3 
5 
Second Array: 
2 
4 
6
-1 
Merged Array:
2 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 3):

Your sorting algorithm is faulty.

It's similar to selection sort, in that you take two elements and swap them if they're out of place.  However, you don't stop the comparisons when you should: when the index `d` is less than the index `i`, the comparison-and-swap based on `arr[d] > arr[i]` is no longer valid.

The inner loop should terminate with `i=d`.

The logic of your sort goes something like this:

On the d-th loop, the elements at `d+1` and to the right are correctly sorted (the larger numbers).  This is true at the beginning, because there are 0 elements correctly sorted to the right of the right-most element.

On each of the outer loops (with the `d` counter), compare the `d-th largest element slot` with every *unsorted* element, and swap if the other element is larger.

This is sufficient to sort the array, but if you begin to compare the `d-th largest element slot` with already-sorted elements to its right, you'll end up with a larger number in the slot than should be.  Therefore, the inner loop should terminate when it reaches `d`.

Comment: This is right on point. Additionally the bothF array is unneeded as it can be replaced with an temp variable (int temp = both[d]) and the whole writing an own sorting algorithm is not needed as there are plenty of existing ones already. For example Arrays.sort(array); is built in into Java.

Comment: @JensJansson but i'm a student and i'm trying to optimize my problem solving skills. Of course i could have solved my problem with a quick google of a sort method, but it wouldn't be optimal practice  for problem solving skills.

Comment: @bdares i'm sure your're right but everything you wrote went over my head, I still don't get it. Can you explain it better?

Comment: Sorry if I sounded rude in my previous comment. I added a top level added to this question as the long explanation didn't fit as a comment. Hope that helps clearing this up.

Answer (score 0):

First I will start with some recommendations:

1. 1.Give end1 and end2 the initial value as the array lengths.
2. The printing part - instead of breaking the loop - loop till i == end(if its not changed by the first part it will stay the array length).
3. One suggestion is to use a "while" statement on the user input to do the reading part (it seems cleaner then breaking the loop- but its OK to do it like you have done too).
4. Try to use more functions.

now to the main thing- why not to insert the numbers from both arrays to the join array keeping them  sorted?

Guiding:

- Keep a marker for each array.
- Iterate over the new join array If    arr1[marker1]> arr2[marker2]
  insert arr2[marker2] to the joint array in the current position.
  and add 1 to marker2. and the opposite.

  (don't forget to choose what happens if the are equal).

This can be achieved because the arrays were sorted in the first place.

Have fun practicing!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have sort of a reverse "selection sort"-algorithm going on there. I made an class that run your code and printed out the output after every swap. Here is the code which is the same as you got in your application with the addition of print.

```
for(int d = both.length -1;d>=0;d--)
 {    
  for(int i = 0; i<both.length; i++)
   {
    if(both[d]<both[i])
     {
      int temp = both[d];
      both[d] = both[i];
      both[i] = temp;
      printArray(both);
     }
  }
}
```

and when we run this on an example array we get this output

```
[9, 8, 7, 6]= 
-> 6879
-> 6789
-> 6798
-> 6978
-> 9678
```

The algorithm actually had the correct answer after two swaps but then it started shuffling them into wrong order. The issue is the inner for loops end parameter. When you have run the outer loop once, you can be certain that the biggest number is in the end. 'd' is here 3 and it will swap out a bigger number every time it encounters it. the if clause comparisions in the first loop is 6-9 (swap), 9-8, 9-7, 9-9. All good so far.

Potential problems comes in the second iteration with 'd' as 2. Array is now [6,8,7,9] and comparisons are 7-6, 7-8 (swap with result [6,7,8,9]), 8-8, 8-9 (swap!!) resulting in [6,7,9,8]. the last swap was the problematic one. We knew that the biggest number was already in the last spot, but we still compare against it. with every gotrough of the whole inner loop it will always find the biggest number (and all other bigger than both[d] that is already in place) and swap it to some wrong position.

As we know that the biggest number will be last after one iteration of the outer loop, we shouldn't compare against it in the second iteration. You sort of lock the 9 in the array and only try to sort the rest, being in this case [6,8,7] where d = 3, value 7. hence, your inner loop `for(int i = 0; i<both.length; i++)` becomes `for(int i = 0; i<=d; i++)`. As an added bonus, you know that in the last iteration `i==d`, and thus the code inside it, `if(both[d]<both[i])` will never be true, and you can further enhance the loop into `for(int i = 0; i<d; i++)`.

In your algorithm you always do four comparisons in the inner loop over four iterations of the outer loop, which means there is a total of 16 comparisons. if we use the `i<d` we'll just do three comparisons in the inner loop on the first iteration of the outer loop, then two, then one. This brings it to a total of six comparisons.

Sorry if too rambling, just wanted to be thorough.